# React Native flex-box align icon and text

Tags: icons, react-native, flexbox

In a `react native` app, I use `'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons'`.

I try to a `<` button with some text. Unfortunately, the `<` icon isn't aligned center with the text. The text is on same line as the `<`  but bottom-aligned instead of middle-aligned.

I didn't have `flex: 1`. The code has been updated.

My code

```
    <TouchableOpacity style={styles.navBarLeftButton}>
       <Icon name="chevron-left" />
       <Text style={styles.buttonText}>My Button</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
```

My styles

```
    navBarLeftButton: {
      flex: 1,
      flexDirection: 'row',
      alignItems: 'center',
      justifyContent: 'flex-start'
      width: 100,
      paddingLeft: 8
    }

    buttonText: {
      color: 'rgba(255,255,255,0.70)',
      fontSize: 14
    }
```

Comment: Next time you stumble upon such issue, try to create a sample project on [RNPlay](https://rnplay.org/) so that community can quickly understand what the problem is and provide a quality-solution.

Answer (score 30):

The answer is to have `flex: 1` and not `height`. I also use `flexDirection: 'row'` because I have two elements.

```
navBarLeftButton: {
  paddingLeft: 8,
  width: 100,
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'row',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'flex-start'
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can also use `<Icon>` inside the `Text`. In that case it will follow `Text`'s style.

```js
<TouchableOpacity style={styles.navBarLeftButton}>
   <Text style={styles.buttonText}>
        <Icon name="chevron-left" />
        My Button
   </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Answer (score -2):

use **active** keyword before a name and also import icon from native-base.

Comment: please elaborate on your answer and also show some example codes. Explain why your answer is different to already posted ansers.