# react native material icon css style

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I have the following react native icon below using material icons. The question is which CSS styling can be used to make the icon appear side by side.

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onButtonPress}>
    <Icon style={{textAlign:"center", flexDirection:"row"}} name="search-web" size={30} color="#009688" />
</TouchableOpacity>


<TouchableOpacity onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate('ConsentDetail')}>

    <Icon style={{textAlign:"center", flexDirection:"row"}} name="filter-variant" color="#009688" size={30} />
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: What do you mean "icon appear side by side"?

Comment: i want the icon to appear horizontally from left to right.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36392521/2405689

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the whole thing with a `view` then give it `flex-direction: 'row'`.

Comment: Showing us your solution codes would be more clear.